# Set and get properties in Buildbot

Tags: windows, buildbot

I just setup a `Buildbot` server using `master.cfg.sample`.
Everything goes well untill I want to get a property I just set in a previous step :

```
factory.addStep(steps.SetPropertyFromCommand(command="echo test", property="test"))
```

This `step` is excuted correctly, and the `property` is created correctly, but I don't know how to retreive it in the next `steps` and use it. Can anyone help me please ?
I'm using `Buildbot 1.4.0` on `Windows`.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say about so outdated version of buildbot. In the modern versions there are Renderables (such as Property, Interpolate and most general Renderer) to use properties: http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/configuration/properties.html#using-properties-in-steps

Answer (score 2):

You just have use util.Interpolate
In your case it will be something like that:

```
factory.addStep(ShellCommand(command=['echo', util.Interpolate('%(prop:test)s')],                                                                                                                                         
        ))
```